# Authentication with 2 entites that implements UserInterface

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security, symfony5

Is it possible to have 2 entities that implement `UserInterface`?

How to use it on my guard to make it check in both classes and with the same firewall?

The idea is that companies can have their own `CVTheque` or shared it (`CVTheque` has a OneToMany relationship with `Company`).

I would like to have `Candidate` and `User` entities.

- CVTheque -> OneToMany -> Candidate
- User -> ManyToOne -> Company.

`Candidate` and `User` will used the same login form to be authenticated on the app. So I don't know if it's possible and how to implement this on my guard authenticator.

They will be redirected to their own dashboard depending to instance of connected user (`Candidate` or `User`).

Answer (score 5):

Recently handled a similar scenario.
In my case, just created a *chain_provider* to encapsulate all entities needed:

```
providers:
    chain_provider:
        chain:
            providers: [provider_one, provider_two]
    provider_one:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\ProviderOne
            property: username
    provider_two:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\ProviderTwo
            property: email
security:
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            # ...
            pattern: ^/login
            provider: chain_provider
```

Comment: I did not know chain_provider. I'll try it tomorrow.
ProviderOne and ProviderTwo both implement UserInterface ?

And what about GuardAuthenticator ? Can u share it please ?

Comment: chain_provider did not exist in SF 5 and SF 4.4

Comment: Yeah,chain provider still exists and all both entities implements UserInterface: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html#chain-user-provider

Comment: Ah yes i was searching for chain_provider :)
You think it's the good way to do ? I'll try it

Comment: Yes @Kévin, you can consider this practice as best.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is possible, let's take basic user authentication and try to tweak it

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfToken;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\GenericEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Contracts\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;

class LoginAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    private $entityManager;
    private $urlGenerator;
    private $csrfTokenManager;
    private $encoder;

    public function __construct(
        EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
        UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator,
        CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager,
        UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
        $this->encoder = $encoder;
        $this->eventDispatcher = $eventDispatcher;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return (
            'login' === $request->attributes->get('_route')&& $request->isMethod('POST') // here you need to specify the other login route if you want to have 2 seperate ones
        );
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'username' => $request->request->get('username'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
            'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
        ];
        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $credentials['username']
        );

        return $credentials;
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }

        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['username' => $credentials['username']]);

        if (!$user) { // here look for user in the 2nd entity, if it will still be null throw the exception
            // fail authentication with a custom error
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Username could not be found.');
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $this->encoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password'], $user->getSalt());
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {        
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('account_index'));
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate('login');
    }
}
```

And that's probably it, we change the authenticator to support 2 routes (login one, login two), and if the first entity does not match username and password try to find user in the other one, you might as well add a hidden input or add attribute in request listener based on the route retrieve it using RequestStack or however you want to indicate each entity.